# Como escrever sobre uma imagem

Tags: java, string, imagem

Achei esse código na internet e fiz algumas mudanças, porém não sei bem o que está dando errado.

Código:

```
public class main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String key = "Lucas Caresia";
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("recibo.png"));
        Graphics graphics = bufferedImage.getGraphics();
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        graphics.drawString(key, 420, 560);
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", new File("recibo.jpg"));
        System.out.println("Image Created");
    }
}
```

Imagem antes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagem depois(visualizada pelo eclipse):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A segunda imagem não está aparecendo

Comment: Exatamente esse o problema, tentei com vários visualizadores de imagens diferentes, porem continua não aparecendo.

Comment: Tem certeza que a imagem `recibo.png` existe e trata-se da imagem que você quer?

Comment: Apesar de vc estar definido o formato como PNG e salvando com extensão ".jpg", o seu código não parece ter nada de errado. Eu testei aqui e funciona "corretamente" (ele só está escrevendo o texto na coordenada errada, mas a imagem gera normalmente). Vou votar como não reproduzido.

Comment: Mesmo eu definindo como PGN ele salva como JPG, porem não defini isso no código, não sei como resolver

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver apenas corrigindo de

```
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", new File("recibo.jpg"));
```

Para

```
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", new File("recibo.png"));
```

Comment: O conteudo era PNG, só a extensão que estava errada, só para explicar, a extensões são apenas para facilitar, mas ainda sim a imagem será PNG, isto é definido pelo conteudo do arquivo ;)